# I can't figure how to use the axios.get() call to get the prices of cryptocurrencies using the coin gecko API

Tags: javascript, api, axios, coingecko

I am trying to just get the prices of bitcoin, ethereum, and dogecoin data using coingeckos api. I am trying to use the axios call axios.get method but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
const cryptSettings = async() => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cdogecoin&vs_currencies=usd')
    console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: "I can't seem to figure it out" is not a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try `response.data` in your `console.log`

Comment: Did you mean `console.log(response.data)`? The answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Yes I apologize I meant console.log(response.data). When I run that I still can error message saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const cryptSettings"